# Is the stream splitting from bash transposable to other languages?

Tags: c++, python, ruby, perl, stream-processing

By *stream splitting* I mean the ability to:

1. filter on the fly the stream content by a first function
2. one part of the stream is processed by a second function
3. the rest of the stream is processed by a third function
4. the stream is never stored (on the fly)

An example is sometime better than a long explanation. This command line use [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) and [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to split the stream:

```
$> cut -f2 file | tee >( grep "AB" | sort | ... ) | grep -v "AB" | tr A B | ...
```

In this example, the stream is split in two: the lines containing `"AB"` and the rest:

```
cut -f2 file ---->- line contains "AB" ->- sort ->- ...
             \--->- does not contain "AB" ->- tr A B ->- ...
```

But I do not like this stream splitting technique because the stream is first duplicated (by `tee`) to be then filtered twice (by `grep` and `grep -v`).

Therefore I wonder if something like *stream splitting* is available in other languages as [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)...

I provide a more complex example below.

---

### Complex `bash` stream splitting

`counter.sh` splits a stream in three sections (begin, middle and end). And for each section, the stream is again split to count the occurrences of symbols `<`, `|` and `>`:

```
#!/bin/bash    
{
  {  tee >( sed -n '1,/^--$/!p' >&3 ) |
            sed -n '1,/^--$/p'        |
     tee >( echo "del at begin:  $(grep -c '<')"    >&4 ) |
     tee >( echo "add at begin:  $(grep -c '>')"    >&4 ) |
          { echo "chg at begin:  $(grep -c '|')"; } >&4
  }  3>&1 1>&2  |
  {  tee >( sed -n '/^--$/,/^--$/!p' >&3 ) |
            sed -n '/^--$/,/^--$/p'        |
     tee >( echo "del at end:    $(grep -c '<')"    >&4 ) |
     tee >( echo "add at end:    $(grep -c '>')"    >&4 ) |
          { echo "chg at end:    $(grep -c '|')"; } >&4
  }  3>&1 1>&2 |
     tee >( echo "del in middle: $(grep -c '<')"    >&4 ) |
     tee >( echo "add in middle: $(grep -c '>')"    >&4 ) |
            echo "chg in middle: $(grep -c '|')"; 
} 4>&1
```

This script is used to count the number of added/changed/deleted lines in sections begin/middle/end. The input of this script is a stream:

```
$> cat file-A
1
22
3
4
5
6
77
8

$> cat file-B
22
3
4
42
6
77
8
99

$> diff --side-by-side file-A file-B | egrep -1 '<|\||>' | ./counter.sh
del at begin:  1
add at begin:  0
chg at begin:  0
del at end:    0
add at end:    1
chg at end:    0
del in middle: 0
add in middle: 0
chg in middle: 1
```

How to implement efficiently a such `counter.sh` in other programming languages without storing the data in a temporary buffer?

---

### Answer

As noted by [Lennart Regebro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214), I am *over-thinking* this question. Of course, all these languages are able to split input streams as answered by [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638354/938111). In pseudo code:

```
while input-stream
{
    case (begin section)
    {
        case (symbol <) aB++ 
        case (symbol |) cB++ 
        case (symbol >) dB++
    }
    case (middle section)
    {
        case (symbol <) aM++ 
        case (symbol |) cM++ 
        case (symbol >) dM++
    } 
    case (ending section)
    {
        case (symbol <) aE++ 
        case (symbol |) cE++ 
        case (symbol >) dE++
    }
}

PrintResult (aB, cB, dB, aM, cM, dM, aE, cE, dE)
```

**Conclusion:** Stream splitting is better done in `python`/`perl`/`awk`/`C++` than using [`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) + [process substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).

Comment: If you want to feed the same data into several processes or threads in Python, you take the data, and you feed it to the processes you want to feed it to. There is now "how would you implement that"; the question simply makes no sense. There is also no performance issue in the question.

Comment: @olibre: No, `shell` does that, as you demonstrated above. I suspect you are overthinking this. Try to ask a concrete question with a concrete problem, and I guess the issue will clarify itself.

Comment: "the stream is never stored within a temporary buffer" - That requirement makes no sense. The stream data will be copied into a variable. You can't avoid that. That variable *is* a temporary buffer.

Comment: In C++ you can use [boost::spirit::multi_pass](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/multi_pass.html) - it converts any input iterator into a forward iterator.

Comment: OK, then the answer is: 1. Make a function that reads in the stream, line by line. 2. for lines that should be processed by one function, you send the data to that function. 3. For lines that should be processed by another function, you send the data to that function. As I said, you are over-thinking this. You fetch the data, then you handle it. Done.

Comment: Yep @LennartRegebro your answer is evident/obvious, I was over-thinking. I kept the `bash` stream philosophy and trying to find that philosophy in other languages... Maybe you can answer? Thank you very much ;)

Comment: @olibre You mentioned Python in previous revisions. Python has `tee` function which allows multi-pass over single-pass sequence by managing temporary buffer. `multi_pass` is analog to `tee` for C++. Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @LennartRegebro. I have added *"on the fly"* requirement on my question. I think my question is no longer *"too broad"* isn't it? Please could you un-hold it? You can answer what you put within your comment... Cheers

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyPanasyuk. I did not aware about neither [Python's tee](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) nor [C++'s tee](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~imaman/programs/teestream.html). Yes indirectly I was looking for such information. Thank you. Hope you will be allowed to write an answer... Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the languages you mention are perfectly suitable for this.

In Perl, I would not use the diff command, I would just use [Algorithm::Diff](http://p3rl.org/Algorithm%3a%3aDiff) on the original files.

Comment: Maybe there is another answer, but the answer I have provided in my question is what I think now. To split a stream in bash, you have to duplicate the stream (`tee`) and to filter each stream twice (example: `grep pattern` and `grep -v pattern`). (I continue my explanation within another comment)

Comment: In Python (or other languages), you can process your stream line after line, and for each line take the decision to process it by a different function/thread/process. This operation meets my definition of *stream splitting* as I have described in the beginning of my question. But I did not thought about that when I asked the question. I saw your answer and also a comment from @LennartRegebro that opened my eyes. (Maybe this is not what you thought when writing your answer...)

Comment: I am not specialized in Perl or Python, but maybe there is stream manipulation features within theses languages that simplifies the writing of a kind of *stream splitting*... If this is true, this can be another answer of my question. Anyway you was the single one you said *"Any of the languages [...] are perfectly suitable for this"* => therefore you got the right answer! Cheers

Comment: Thanks @ysth I will update the answer within the question to make it more clear. (I keep my comments above as inspiration...) Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Tee is just a C program using basic system calls, you can implement it in any language that provides access to the system libraries.

A google search for

tee in my favorite language

should find all the answers you need.

Comment: Hi Fred. Do you means for example this [Python's tee](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) or this [C++'s tee](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~imaman/programs/teestream.html)? I did not aware about these possibilities. I was not looking for such information, but thank you for your tip +1. I have rework my question. Hope you like this rephrase version. Cheers ;)